# Puppy Linux internet connection is so slow

Tags: internet, puppy-linux

I am running Puppy Linux from USB and I am using my phone as modem. I have 10 Mbps connection in my phone but Puppy Linux is loading pages with 10-20 kb/s speed in Chrome.

I`ve used Frisbee to connect internet. Why is loading so slow?

Comment: How do you connect to your phone? If with a USB cable, make sure it is a USB2.0 cable.

Comment: I am using Android's wifi tethering feature.

Answer (score -2):

Right-click on the WiFi sign and enable WiFi Polling. Your problem will be fixed.

Comment: Hello, welcome on the Unix SE! Contrary to most internet sites, we at least try to take care on spelling.

Comment: I've edited your post to fix the spelling and punctuation. However, this answer still isn't useful as it doesn't explain "*Why* is loading so slow?"